# Install cryst font on macOS 10.14 for pdflatex and lualatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex, luatex, installing-fonts

I want to use following font in my current document with pdflatex and lualatex

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cryst

Following MWE compiles successfully

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{cry}{\hyphenchar\font=-1}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{cry}{m}{n}{ <-> cryst}{}
\newcommand{\cry}[1]{{\usefont{U}{cry}{m}{n} \symbol{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node (a) at (0,0) {\cry{2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, right now I get only a bitmap font

[image]

Log file contains only a single line to a cryst file:

```
/Users/hotschke/Library/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/pk
/ljfour/public/cryst/cryst.600pk
```

And most importantly my printer prints only following error

```
ERROR: limitcheck
OFFENDING COMMAND: imagemask

STACK:

(r)
(Sys/Start)
(Sys/Start)
```

[image]

I have MacTeX 2018 on macOS 10.14 installed.

As far as I understand the question [load custom font in miktex 2.9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351106/load-custom-font-in-miktex-2-9) concerning using 'cryst' on MikTeX, the description given in the [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cryst/README) of the font 'cryst' is outdated.

Can one help me to configure it properly in a texmf local directory?

Afaik, the texmf local base directory on macOS by default is

<s>`$HOME/Library/texmf`</s>
`/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/`

See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i) for details why you should **not** install fonts into your home folder. Other files such as packages are probably be fine (http://tug.org/mactex/faq/faq.html#atqm05down).

**General description of how to install a font is given here:**

https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html

The site https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall-personal.html also warns *twice* about installing fonts into a personal folder.

I have followed the README the first four steps copying the relevant files into the texmf local tree:

```
❯ TEXMFLOCAL=$(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL)
❯ echo $TEXMFLOCAL
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local

❯ mkdir -p $TEXMFLOCAL/fonts/{tfm,source,afm,type1}/cryst1
❯ cp $(kpsewhich cryst.tfm) $TEXMFLOCAL/fonts/tfm/cryst1/
❯ cp $(kpsewhich cryst.mf)  $TEXMFLOCAL/fonts/source/cryst1/
❯ cp $(kpsewhich cryst.afm) $TEXMFLOCAL/fonts/afm/cryst1/
❯ cp $(kpsewhich cryst.pfb) $TEXMFLOCAL/fonts/type1/cryst1/

/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
❯ tree -P '*cryst*' --prune
.
└── fonts
    ├── afm
    │   └── cryst1
    │       └── cryst.afm
    ├── source
    │   └── cryst1
    │       └── cryst.mf
    ├── tfm
    │   └── cryst1
    │       └── cryst.tfm
    └── type1
        └── cryst1
            └── cryst.pfb

9 directories, 4 files
```

Now, I am not sure how to update the files

- `config.ps` (for dvips) with `p +cryst1.map`
- `pdftex.cfg` for pdftex with `map +cryst1.map`
- and what I have to do for lualatex.

**UPDATE** Extract of the README (without the 'trivial' steps of copying files):

```
Tell dvips (for PostScript output) where to find the files.
To this end, insert the following line into the file config.ps:
p +cryst1.map
(config.ps is in a directory like \texmf\dvips\config
or /usr/share/texmf/dvips/config).
If you use pdfTeX, insert
map +cryst1.map
to your pdftex.cfg file
(in \texmf\pdftex\config or /usr/share/texmf/pdftex/config).

Create a new file cryst1.map in a new subdirectory of the directory
of map files (e.g. \texmf\dvips\cryst1 or /usr/share/texmf/dvips/cryst1).
The file cryst1.map consists of one line:
cryst cryst1 <cryst.pfb

Finally, tell TeX which new files and directories exist. This is done
by a command like
initexmf -u  for MikTeX under Windows
or run texhash under root in the shell of Linux RedHat.
```

Comment: Is there no .map file? You need that and then run `updmap-user`.

Comment: No, there is not one. The `README` says I have to create it myself "Create a new file cryst1.map in a new subdirectory of the directory of map files. The file cryst1.map consists of one line: `cryst cryst1 <cryst.pfb`".

Answer (score 4):

The easy method is to add this line to your document:

```
 \pdfmapline{=cryst cryst1 <cryst.pfb}
```

To setup the map file create a small file `cryst.map` with the content

```
 cryst cryst1 <cryst.pfb
```

Put it in `texmf-local/fonts/map/cryst`

Then run on a command line

```
 mktexlsr
```

and

```
 updmap-sys --enable Map=cryst.map
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It pointed me into the right direction. However, I had to run `$ updmap -user --enable Map=cryst.map` so that the pfb file under `/Users/hotschke/Library/texmf/fonts/type1/cryst1/cryst.pfb` was found by pdflatex/lualatex.

Comment: Does your first suggestion require that I have to place the pfb file in the same directory as the tex file?

Comment: on my system the pfb is in texmf-dist from texlive 2018. And normally you shouldn't use updmap --user but only the -sys variant. But now that you did it, remember that you have now local map-files and probably will have to run updmap regularly to update them. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i

Comment: Yes, I know I should not have invoked in the past `updmap --user`. There was a big warning when I did it. However, I felt that the directory `~/Library/texmf` is the correct one for my local additions and not under `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`. Anyhow, your advice & help is very welcome.