# How can the font cryst be used in asymptote in particular with WebGL output?

Tags: fonts, asymptote

How can the font [cryst](https://ctan.org/pkg/cryst) be used in [asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) in particular with WebGL output?

#### 1. PDF output of Asymptote

Consider my file `label3zoom.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

% \DeclareFontFamily{U}{cry}{\hyphenchar\font=-1}
% \DeclareFontShape{U}{cry}{m}{n}{ <-> cryst}{}
% \newcommand{\cry}[1]{{\usefont{U}{cry}{m}{n} \symbol{#1}}}

\begin{document}

% Hello cryst ``\cry{41}'' % works

\begin{asydef}
import three;
texpreamble("\DeclareFontFamily{U}{cry}{\hyphenchar\font=-1}");
texpreamble("\DeclareFontShape{U}{cry}{m}{n}{ <-> cryst}{}");
texpreamble("\newcommand{\cry}[1]{{\usefont{U}{cry}{m}{n} \symbol{#1}}}");
\end{asydef}

\begin{center}
\begin{asy}
    currentlight=Headlamp;
    size(400pt,400pt);
    currentprojection=oblique;
    draw(scale3(4)*extrude("Hello cryst ``\cry{41}''",2Z), material(blue));
\end{asy}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The sequence

```
$ pdflatex label3zoom.tex
$ asy label3zoom-*.asy
$ pdflatex label3zoom.tex
```

gives me following output:

[image]

As you can see the `\cry{41}` command does not produce any output. In pdflatex `\cry{41}` prints a little square with spikes in the corners

[image]

Why is there only whitespace in the output of Asymptote and how can I fix this?

#### 2. WebGL output of Asymptote

One can generate with

```
$ asy --version
Asymptote version 2.70 [(C) 2004 Andy Hammerlindl, John C. Bowman, Tom Prince]

ENABLED OPTIONS:
WebGL    3D HTML rendering
...
```

and the flag `-f html`

```
$ asy -f html label3zoom.asy
```

HTML pages with WebGL rendering. This works for the official example [label3zoom.asy](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/3Dwebgl/label3zoom.asy).

I assume when the problem with the pdf output is fixed, the webgl output might work as well. But I will see.

I am on macOS 10.15.7 using MacTeX-2021 based on current TeXLive 2021.

Comment: I managed to get a bit further with `pen fpen=font("U","cry","m","n");
    label("\symbol{41}",(0mm,-10mm),fpen+blue);` but I didn't manage to put this inside an `extrude` command.

Comment: I guess Asymptote current only for **smooth** and **continuous** symbols, while `\cry{41}` is not smooth. You can test another math symbols.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, efforts and thoughts. They pointed me in the direction to check whether the vector-based font of cryst is actually used. [An old question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474717/8917) of mine was about the proper installation of the font cryst. My recent new installation of TeXLive 2021 made it necessary to update the font configuration of cryst once again which I missed and apparently solved this question as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ensure that Type-1 (vector-based) font of the package [cryst](https://ctan.org/pkg/cryst) is used

([files `cryst.afm` and `cryst.pfb`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cryst) )

In order to check what kind of font is currently used, compile a pdf document using the cryst font without asymptote, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{cry}{\hyphenchar\font=-1}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{cry}{m}{n}{ <-> cryst}{}
\newcommand{\cry}[1]{{\usefont{U}{cry}{m}{n} \symbol{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Hello cryst ``\cry{41}''.

\end{document}
```

Then check the log file for font entries. If a pixel-based font is used following type of entry can be found (search pattern `cryst.[0-9]*pk`)

```
/Users/hotschke/Library/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/pk
/ljfour/public/cryst/cryst.600pk
```

Also a visual inspection with a pdf viewer by larger zoom levels reveals whether a vector- or pixel-based font is used.

After I followed the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474734/8917) of an old question

[Install cryst font on macOS 10.14 for pdflatex and lualatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474717/install-cryst-font-on-macos-10-14-for-pdflatex-and-lualatex),

the log entry will point to the file `cryst.pfb`.

Now when I run the given example in the question, I get

[image]